# Can you riddle me this?

Tags: riddle

> Quivering am I,
> no words destroy me,
> I am what can defend you with no end.

Can you tell me what I am?

Comment: Honesty/truth. Straight shooter for the quiver.

Comment: nope, that is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Apollo

Quivering am I

> Apollo is the god of archery

No mortal halts me

> He speaks like a god

Thus no words destroy me

> He is the god of poetry which is basically the god of words.

Comment: That is a good guess but it's incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Quivering am I,

> I think you are a tongue which quivers while we speak.

no words destroy me,

> The tongue is not harmed while we speak.

I am what can defend you with no end.

> We defend ourselves by talking back when needed.

Comment: Can you please hide your explanation behind spoiler blocks (>!), as the other answer does?

Comment: Just use the "edit" button. It is on the bottom of your answer, next to "share" and "follow"

Comment: Sorry, that's incorrect, not everybody defends themselves

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> One's faith?

Quivering am I

> as in [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1w6t9p2) (quiverfull)

no words destroy me

> Faith is a matter of personal belief

I am what can defend you with no end

> As long as it is believed

Comment: sorry, faith can be faltered and I'm not sure how it defends you.